# Disable inline editing sharepoint 2013 through powershell

Tags: powershell

I have migrated a sharepoint 2010 list with inline editing enabled to sharepoint 2013 and now this setting is not viewable through the GUI, thus I cannot disable it. Is there a powershell cmdlet for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable inline editing through powershell, in SharePoint 2010 or in 2013 (for lists upgraded with this property).

Source: http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/blog/2013/05/24/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-powershell-update-view/

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
### Add the site collection 
### $siteURL = Read-Host "Enter the site collection URL"
$siteURL = "http://sitecollection/sites/somesitename" 
Write-Host "____________________________________"
Write-Host "Checking site collection: $siteURL"
Write-Host "____________________________________"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL) 
### Arrays used to loop through views and display what is happening
$webUrl = @()
$listName = @()
$viewUrl = @()
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{     
Write-Host "Checking Web: $web"     
foreach ($list in $web.lists)        
{         
#Write-Host "Debug: Checking $list"
        foreach ($view in $list.Views)
            {
            if($view.InLineEdit -eq "TRUE")                 
                {                 
                Write-Host "Progress: Found InLineEdit in $view"                 
                $webUrl += $web.Url                     
                $listName += $list.Title                 
                $viewUrl += $view.Url                
                }            
            }        
}    
}

# Cycle through the views found and reset each view's Inline Edit property
$numViews = $viewUrl.Count
Write-Host "____________________________________"
Write-Host "Number of Views to update $numViews" 
$i=0
foreach ($viewUrl in $viewUrl)   
{    
  $web = $webUrl[$i]     
  $list = $listName[$i]     
  $i++     
  $doUpdate = $true            
  $spWeb = Get-SPWeb $web     
  Try        
   {         
    # Check that the view URL you have is actually a view URL and not a web part view         
    $spView = $spWeb.GetViewFromUrl("$viewUrl")        
   }          
   Catch [system.exception]    
    {        
     "The view URL found is not a valid view and may be a view used on a web part page."        
     "URL being checked was: $spWeb - $list - $viewURL"        
     $doUpdate = $false    
    }     
    If ($doUpdate)       
     {         
      Write-Host "View being updated: $spWeb - $list - $spView"         
      $spView.InLineEdit = $null         
      $spView.Update()        
     }    
 }
 $site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `List Settings` of the list in concern.
2. Go to `Advanced Settings`.
3. Go to `Quick Edit` section.
4. Click `No` radio button.
5. Click `Ok`.

Let us know if it helped you.

Comment: what i mean is inline editing. NOT quick editing. inline is an unsuported feature in sharepoint 2013. see this blog post: http://www.vlieshout.net/disable-inline-editing-on-migrated-sites/

Comment: Do you mean that after migration to SharePoint  2013, this feature is still working fine. But, you want to remove it, as you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

this feature breaks the customized list form, more specifically the rich multi lines text boxes are not auto expanding. I ended up deleting all views and recreating them..